# Memory location has different value inside and outside of functions

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a glusterfs plugin for collectd in C that uses the glusterfs libraries to make the actual RPC calls. I've managed to get a standalone C program working that's basically just cobbled together parts of the gluster CLI.

However, when I port that code to a collectd library, I'm getting some weird behavior when making function calls that use symbols in the gluster libraries. Outside the function calls, memory location X refers to a struct with non-null members. Inside the function calls, memory location X refers to a struct with null members. This is causing the function to fail and return NULL instead of a pointer to a struct, which of course causes the RPC to fail.

Here is some output from GDB from stepping through the program. You can see that the members of the struct living in `0x7fffec0231b0` change when entering the function. Note that I've removed some of the members from the print just to make it a bit more legible:

```
(gdb) next
718                 frame = create_frame (THIS, state.ctx->pool);
(gdb) print state.ctx.pool
$22 = (struct call_pool *) 0x7fffdc022740
(gdb) print *state.ctx.pool
$23 = {..., frame_mem_pool = 0x7fffdc0227e0, stack_mem_pool = 0x7fffdc0586d0}
(gdb) print *{struct call_pool *}0x7fffdc022740
$24 = {..., frame_mem_pool = 0x7fffdc0227e0, stack_mem_pool = 0x7fffdc0586d0}
(gdb) step
create_frame (xl=0x7ffff4fc96e0 <global_xlator>, pool=pool@entry=0x7fffdc022740) at stack.c:17
17      {
(gdb) print pool
$26 = (call_pool_t *) 0x7fffdc022740
(gdb) print *pool
$27 = {..., frame_mem_pool = 0x0, stack_mem_pool = 0x0}
(gdb) print *{struct call_pool*}0x7fffdc022740
$28 = {..., frame_mem_pool = 0x0, stack_mem_pool = 0x0}
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  create_frame (xl=0x7ffff4fc96e0 <global_xlator>, pool=pool@entry=0x7fffdc022740) at stack.c:17
0x00007ffff5400492 in profiler_callback (d=<optimized out>) at src/glusterfs.c:718
718                 frame = create_frame (THIS, state.ctx->pool);
Value returned is $29 = (call_frame_t *) 0x0
(gdb) print state.ctx.pool
$30 = (struct call_pool *) 0x7fffdc022740
(gdb) print *{struct call_pool*}0x7fffdc022740
$31 = {..., frame_mem_pool = 0x7fffdc0227e0, stack_mem_pool = 0x7fffdc0586d0}
```

As you can see, the memory location inside the function seems to refer to a struct that has different values, as its members are null inside the function, but not outside of it.

Perhaps worth noting, `create_frame` is from a gluster library, which is separate from my collectd library. The behavior I described is also happening with another function from a gluster library.

EDIT:

Full source can be seen [here](https://github.com/squarebracket/collectd/blob/master/src/glusterfs.c)

Here's a bit of a reduced snippet:

```
// globals
struct cli_state state = {0, };
struct rpc_clnt *global_rpc;
rpc_clnt_prog_t *cli_rpc_prog;

int
glusterfs_ctx_defaults_init ()
{
        call_pool_t   *pool = NULL;
        glusterfs_ctx_t *ctx = state.ctx;

        pool = GF_CALLOC (1, sizeof (call_pool_t),
                          mt_call_pool_t);

        /* stack_mem_pool size 256 * 128 */
        pool->stack_mem_pool = mem_pool_new (call_stack_t, 16);
        if (!pool->stack_mem_pool)
                return 1;

        ctx->pool = pool;

        return 0;

}

void * profiler_callback (void* d) {
    int ret = 0;
        call_frame_t            *frame = NULL;
        // function from gluster library returns
        // pthread_getspecific (this_xlator_key);
        // so essentially a thread-specific variable
        xlator_t                *xlator = (*__glusterfs_this_location());

        // here, state.ctx->pool->stack_mem_pool is not null
        frame = create_frame (xlator, xlator->ctx->pool);
        // it is also not null here. however, frame is null
        // since state.ctx->pool->stack_mem_pool *is* null
        // inside create_frame
        if (!frame)
                goto out;

out:
        INFO("Exiting with: %d", ret);
        kill_self();

        return NULL;

}

int
read_stats (void)
{
    int ret = -1;
    glusterfs_ctx_t   *ctx = NULL;
    xlator_t * xlator = NULL;

        ctx = glusterfs_ctx_new ();
        if (!ctx)
                return ENOMEM;

        ret = glusterfs_globals_init (ctx);
        if (ret)
                return ret;

        // function from gluster library returns
        // pthread_getspecific (this_xlator_key);
        // so essentially a thread-specific variable
        xlator = (*__glusterfs_this_location());

        // Sets ctx.pool.stack_mem_pool
        ret = glusterfs_ctx_defaults_init (xlator);
        if (ret) {
                return ret;
        }

        state.ctx = ctx;

        pthread_mutex_init (&cond_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init (&cond, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init (&conn_mutex, NULL);
        pthread_cond_init (&conn, NULL);

        ret = pthread_create ((&(state.input)), NULL, profiler_callback, &state);
        if (ret) {
            ERROR("problem! %d", ret);
        }

        ret = event_dispatch (state.ctx->event_pool);
out:

        return ret;
}

void module_register(void) {
  plugin_register_read("glusterfs", read_stats);
}
```

`module_register` registers the `read_stats` function with collectd, which it then calls every interval period.

Comment: Is `call_pool_t` in the called context in fact the same type as `struct call_pool` in the original context?  If the types are not identical then your debugging output says nothing interesting.

Comment: We are in any case unlikely to be able to provide much insight without some code -- a [mcve], mind, not your whole program.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that `call_pool_t` is just a typedef of `struct call_pool`.

Comment: As for a minimal example, I can't even fathom how to create such a reproducible problem from scratch. From my understanding of C, this shouldn't happen. I'll try to pull out relevant snippets so you can at least get an understanding of the call flow.

Comment: Why is this unexpected behaviour? What is the scope of your variable? What does valgrind (or some memory checker) say about the situation?

Comment: @squarebracket, it is a good first guess that the problem is in your code, not the gluster code.  Thus, presenting sufficient of your own code to exhibit the context of the call has a decent chance of being of help.  That is the bare minimum you can provide if you hope to get any useful analysis.